TempDB being created on different drive than specified in config - SQL 2019
Doing a fresh FCI install - specifying dedicated tempdb data and log drive and the install is bombing due to insufficient space on system db drive due to tempdb.... Any idea on a root cause? Verified config many times - hundreds of installs under my belt... Can work around to correct but id rather understand whats going on.

Update: Stepping through logs it seems the process creates tempdb then moves it. resolution was specifying a smaller size that would fit on the system drive
